# Intervals and arithmetic

Tags: interval-arithmetic

Is it mathematically right to write intervals in equations?
For example is it right to write this: 
$[a_{1};b_{1}] = \frac{[a_{0};b_{0}]}{2}$

Comment: Hmm, the meaning can be inferred so I'd say it's okay, but others may say no and others may argue otherwise.  If you do you must not get confused and start treating [a_0;b_0]/2 as a number. You must never forget it is simply a set.

Comment: It's for a school report, do you think the professor will be ok with this ? Is there another mean to explain that? Something more rigorous ?

Comment: No, I predict the professor will not like it.  And if he does, why risk it. Um, why not simply write:  $[a_1;b_1]=[\frac {a_0}2;\frac {b_0}2] $

Comment: Nice, thank you. I don't know why I hadn't thought about this, it's so trivial...